# NSTableview with 2 vertical headers

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nssearchfield, nspopover, nstableheaderview

I try to achieve something like this:[image]

I got a view-based NSTableview and i'd like to show the search results in this tableview. But i need to show the search results for web and for the local library search separately.
So i am wondering how i can get 2 headers vertically aligned in a NSTableview, or is something different used in the shown picture ?

Thanks